# Scrapy reverses order of arguments in url Python

Tags: python, asp.net, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm running a scraper to crawl from http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx to the office rosters.

The office roster addresses look like this: http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?p=agentResults.asp&OfficeID=8627 - but Scrapy crawls http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?OfficeID=8627&p=agentResults.asp which is a dead page. **The two parts after .aspx are swapped.**

I even went so far as to manually load every single address explicitly as start_urls, and it still happens.

I'm using the most recent Scrapy on python-2.7, Windows 8.1

Code Sample:

```
class JLSSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'JLS'
    allowed_domains = ['johnlscott.com']
    # start_urls = ['http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx']

    rules = (
        Rule(callback="parse_start_url", follow=True),)

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('hrefnums.csv', 'rbU') as ifile:
            read = csv.reader(ifile)
            for row in read:
                for col in row:
                    # I have a csv of the office IDs: (Just letting it crawl through them creates the same issue)
                    yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?p=agentResults.asp&OfficeID=%s" % col)


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        items = []
        sel = Selector(response)
        sections = sel.xpath("//tr/td/table[@id='tbAgents']/tr")
        for section in sections:
            item = JLSItem()
            item['name'] = section.xpath("td[2]/text()")[0].extract().replace(u'\xa0', ' ').strip()         
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Comment: please improve your question, improve the spider, and give a correct code that could be tested.

Comment: I'm confused.  I stated the problem clearly in the body and the title - the "p=agentRestults.asp" and "OfficeID=XXXX" are switched when Scrapy crawls any of the urls.  I included whatever part of the Spider code I think is relevant.  I'm not an expert coder, but I've scraped dozens of large sites by modifying the tutorial.  Can you be more specific about what I need to do or am doing wrong (in regards to SO)?

Comment: I've added as much as I can think to add.  It's a spider made from the scrapy tutorial base.  To let it just crawl, comment the `start_requests` function and uncomment the `start_urls` list.  Also have to create JLSItem, but it's easy enough to see from the log that it swaps the sections of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problems crawling like this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request


class JLSSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'JLS'
    allowed_domains = ['johnlscott.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request("http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?p=agentResults.asp&OfficeID=8627", callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print response.body
```

Comment: I ended up copying and pasting my code into your code out of frustration... and it worked.  The only thing I can think of is that I had more imports, like importing the LinkExtractor.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the swapping of url parts by using the option `canonicalize=False` like in the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class JLSSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'JLS'
    allowed_domains = ['johnlscott.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx']

    rules = (
        # http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?p=agentResults.asp&OfficeID=7859
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=('p=agentResults.asp&OfficeID=', 
                ), 
                canonicalize=False
            ),
            callback='parse_roster',
            follow=True),
    )

    def parse_roster(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Exact same code, I get a ton of `2015-04-22 12:59:09-0700 [JLS] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx?OfficeID=7866&p=agentResults.asp> (referer: http://www.johnlscott.com/agent-search.aspx)]`

Comment: So you can add your parse code to parse_roster to get the data.